# How do I move a Sitecore 9.1 instance from one computer to another?

Tags: installation

I have a working Sitecore 9.1 instance on my local laptop.  I would like to move it from my laptop to a server.

Is there a preferred method for doing this?  I can backup the Core, Master and Web databases.  And I can zip up the website root.  Is it just a matter of restoring the 3 databases to the SQL Server on the server and then unzipping the website root folder?

I know that I would also need to modify my connection strings possibly.  And my Solr cores may be named differently on the server.  So I might need to go through my config files and edit the Solr core names to match the cores that are already on the server.

Is there more to it than that?  Is there a different method that I should use to move a Sitecore 9.1 instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The safest way would be to backup your master & core databases, install 9.1 on your new machine and then restore the master and core databases.

If you have custom code, you would then need to deploy that to your new instance. Technically there, you *could* copy over the files from the webroot to the new site and just not overwrite any files, then your `ConnectionStrings.config` would still be valid etc... But you would be safer just re-deploying the code.

You can't simply copy the files over, its more complicated than that. You have xConnect, Identity Server and the main Site, plus IIS Applications, Bindings and Host file entries to make, Solr configuration etc..

Trying to copy all that manually would be very prone to error and probably take longer than just installing Sitecore and restoring the databases.

Comment: Hi Richard, I am new to Sitecore and I am working on an exiting Sitecore Project. So I have Sitecore project with code in Helix structure and I do not have any Sitecore database so I am wondering, is there any way to restore the existing Sitecore project with Core and Master databases.

Comment: Please ask a new question rather than commenting on an older question.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that install clean instance of Sitecore 9.1 in new machine, create Sitecore package for files and items of any custom work in current machine and install the package in new machine.

Comment: If it was different versions of Sitecore, this answer might be more appropriate, but if it is the same version and just migrating the same sites over, then I think the full database backup might be more complete.